# How to make a CSV file with a list and a dictionary for each list item?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I have a `list` and I create a `dictionary` based on each list item, I want to write a `CSV` file as follows:

```
ListItem, key1, key2, key3
li1, value1, value2, value3
li2, value1, value2, value3
```

This is how I try to do this, but I think my code overwrites the first line with each iteration, and I do not know how to enter the list item in the first column. Can you give me a hand, please?

```
import pandas as pd
import random


def CreateDict(li):
    dict = {}
    dict['x'] = random.randrange(1, li)
    dict['y'] = random.randrange(1, li)
    print(dict)
    return dict

mylist = [10, 20, 30]
for li in mylist:
    mydict = CreateDict(li)
    df = pd.DataFrame([mydict])  # Here
    df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

I want this structure in `CSV` file:

```
LI, x, y
10, 6, 2
20, 10, 14
30, 25, 27
```

But I get this as an output:

```
x,y
25,27
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question wasn't cleary defined, I'll write a simple example creating a csv from a dictionary in the format you asked for. The dict looks like:

```py
myd = {"k1":["v11","v12"],"k2":["v21","v22"],"k3":["v31","v32"]}
```

All you need is adding an index column (using `reset_index`), and rename it to your desired name:

```py
pd.DataFrame(your_dict).reset_index().rename({"index":"ListItem"}).to_csv("your.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what exactly I try to do. I edited the code part with an example list and dictionary to make it more clear.